# How to set value multiple location with one iteration in df.at

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
   a   b   c
0  1   6  11
1  2   7  12
2  3   8  13
3  4   9  14
4  5  10  15
```

and another dataframe looks like this,

```
  column  index
0      a      0
1      b      2
2      c      4
```

in this second dataframe it contains index and column, from this df i want to access first df and replace this [row,column] value to 1996.

I tried this,

```
df.at[df_index['index'],df_index['column']]=1996

      a     b     c
0  1996  1996  1996
1     2     7    12
2  1996  1996  1996
3     4     9    14
4  1996  1996  1996
```

But not working as expected,

It works when I tried like this,

```
for v in df_index.values:
    df.at[v[1],v[0]]=1996

      a     b     c
0  1996     6    11
1     2     7    12
2     3  1996    13
3     4     9    14
4     5    10  1996
```

Question:

1. why my first attempt fails
2. what is the minimal way to achieve this in pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.at` and `pd.DataFrame.iat` are used for accessing and setting scalar values. Therefore, you need to loop over every combination of (row, column) labels to set values via these methods. You cannot feed series or arrays into these indexers.

One possibility is to extract the `numpy` array representation, use vectorised indexing to update the array, then feed into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
vals = df.values
cols = df.columns.get_loc

vals[df_index['index'], df_index['column'].map(cols)] = 1996

res = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

print(res)

      a     b     c
0  1996     6    11
1     2     7    12
2     3  1996    13
3     4     9    14
4     5    10  1996
```